# How to get the values of an attribute after content1.select() returns a list?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I'm trying to extract the sound download link of this [url](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/aimer) with

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

user_agent = {'User-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36"}

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/graduate'
r = session.get(url, headers = headers)           
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

entry_name = soup.h2.text 
content1 = soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling')
sound_url = pandas.DataFrame({'LINK': [''], 'NAME': ['']})

temp1 = content1.select('.hwd_sound.sound.audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr')
print(temp1)
```

whose result is

```
[<a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a>, <a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0037420.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a>, <a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/FR-W0071410.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a>, <a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/fr_bachelier.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a>, <a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/63854.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a>]
```

My desire is to extract the value of attribute `data-src-mp3` from each element of the list `temp1`. I try `content1.select('.hwd_sound.sound.audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr').get('data-src-mp3')` but the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-357ee676f699> in <module>
     12 sound_url = pandas.DataFrame({'LINK': [''], 'NAME': ['']})
     13 
---> 14 temp1 = content1.select('.hwd_sound.sound.audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr').get('data-src-mp3')
     15 
     16 print(temp1)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py in __getattr__(self, key)
   2158     def __getattr__(self, key):
   2159         """Raise a helpful exception to explain a common code fix."""
-> 2160         raise AttributeError(
   2161             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key
   2162         )

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'get'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?
```

appears. Could you please elaborate on how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select() retruns list of elements you need to iterate the list and then use the `element['attributename']`

```
temp1 = content1.select('.hwd_sound.sound.audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr')
for item in temp1:
    print(item['data-src-mp3'])
```

If the attribute not there you will receive an error.I would suggest include the attribute as well while select the element.

```
temp1 = content1.select('.hwd_sound.sound.audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr[data-src-mp3]')
for item in temp1:
    print(item['data-src-mp3'])
```

---

```
temp1 = content1.select('.hwd_sound.sound.audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr[data-src-mp3]')
print([item['data-src-mp3'] for item in temp1])
```

Comment: I'm surprised that we have no choice but to use the loop `for` :(

Comment: I would like to ask if there is other command (without loop) that returns all the values of the attribute `data-src-mp3`.

Comment: @LAD : If you are looking for single element you can use `select_one()` like `temp1 = content1.select_one('.hwd_sound.sound.audio_play_button.icon-volume-up.ptr[data-src-mp3]')
print(temp1['data-src-mp3'])`

Comment: Sadly, I need all of them, not just a single one.

Comment: @LAD : You need to iterate this however you can returns the out put as list.check the updated answer.